# SQL - repeat same query with slight changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL:  I am currently copying the same query a number of times and slightly changing it - I am adding or changing one of the variables in the select and group by statement.  The problem is that each query is many lines of code, and so in total, there are lots and lots of lines of code.  Is there a neater solution?

I would be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: edit the question add some sample data (i.e. tried query) would helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't a stored procedure with dynamic SQL suit you? Like shown here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure

Comment: Two words: Dynamic SQL.

Comment: Post the query. Forse example you could create a view and then filter and group by from that view. Or use a Dynamic SQL approach

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)